# Integral Hölder bound

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, inequality

I was wondering if it is possible to find the following bound or if not, find a counterexample of it.

Let $f\in C_0^1$ (compactly supported continously differentiable, in particular $\alpha$-Hölder continuous with $\alpha \in (0,1))$. Then
$$I:=\left|\int_0^t \int_{\mathbb{R}} f''(x) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi s}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2s}}dxds\right|\leq C \|f\|_{\alpha}$$
where $\|f\|_{\alpha} := \|f\|_{\infty} + \sup_{x\neq y} \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}}$ denotes the Hölder norm.

If $\alpha=1$, i.e. $f$ is Lipschitz with compact support it is true. One has to integrate by parts and bound $f'$ by its uniform norm. If $f$ is just bounded, it is not true, doing integration by parts twice does not help, the $ds$ integral explodes. So I was wondering, what about something in between? Not Lipschitz, not just bounded, but Hölder-continuous! Is it then true?

Trial:

$$I= \left|\int_0^t \frac{1}{s\sqrt{2\pi s}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f'(x) x e^{-\frac{x^2}{2s}}dxds\right|$$
so the question reduces to showing:
$$\left| \int_{\mathbb{R}} f'(x) x e^{-\frac{x^2}{2s}}\right| \leq \|f\|_{\alpha} g(\alpha,s)$$
where $g$ is some function s.t.
$$\int_0^t \frac{1}{s\sqrt{2\pi s}} g(\alpha,s) ds \leq C_{\alpha}<\infty.$$

Is this a known result? Is there a counterexample? It could also happen that it is true for some $\alpha$'s! (I'm afraid it is true only for $\alpha \in (1/2,1)$ :)
Thank you very much for your help!